# Ruby: How to "call method" within the Initializer method for a class?

Tags: ruby

I am currently working on writing a class that has two methods. The first method is an initialize method and the second is a method that calculates the most frequent word in a line of text that has been fed into it. I am given instructions of the what methods in the class are suppose to accomplish in the form of comments. One such instruction to be implemented in the initialize method, that I don't understand what is exactly being asked of me is:

> #* call the calculate_word_frequency() method.

I have tried the following to perform the instructions but I fear I simply don't understand the context of the instructions:

```
def initialize(content, line_number)
  @content = content
  @line_number = line_number
  calculate_word_frequency()
end
```

I am provided a way to self test if the code performs the expected duties with a rspec testing unit so I know this doesn't produce the results expected.

Additionally, I am having trouble finding examples in which the initialize method in a class is used for anything other than initializing input variables. I thought this may be a helpful direction to look into with my problem for understanding how calling on another method from within the same class, in the initialize method, accomplishes anything.

Code with instructions in the form of comments:

```
#Implement a class called LineAnalyzer.
class LineAnalyzer
    #Implement the following read-only attributes in the LineAnalyzer class.
    #* highest_wf_count - a number with maximum number of occurrences for a single word (calculated)
    #* highest_wf_words - an array of words with the maximum number of occurrences (calculated)
    #* content,         - the string analyzed (provided)
    #* line_number      - the line number analyzed (provided)
  attr_reader :highest_wf_count, :highest_wf_words, :content, :line_number

  #Add the following methods in the LineAnalyzer class.
  #* initialize() - taking a line of text (content) and a line number
  #* calculate_word_frequency() - calculates result

    #Implement the initialize() method to:
    #* take in a line of text and line number
    #* initialize the content and line_number attributes
    #* call the calculate_word_frequency() method.
  def initialize(content, line_number)
    @content = content
    @line_number = line_number
  end

    #Implement the calculate_word_frequency() method to:
    #* calculate the maximum number of times a single word appears within
    #  provided content and store that in the highest_wf_count attribute.
    #* identify the words that were used the maximum number of times and
    #  store that in the highest_wf_words attribute.
  def calculate_word_frequency()
    words = content.split(" ")
    frequency = Hash.new
    highest_wf_count = Hash.new
    highest_wf_words = Hash.new
    words.each { |word| frequencies[word.downcase] += 1}
    frequencies = frequency.sort_by {|a, b| b }
    frequencies.reverse!
    highest_wf_count = frequencies.values[0].push
    highest_wf_words = frequencies.keys[0].push
  end
end
```

Any help on interpreting what the instruction in question is meaning to have accomplished by calling an outside method from within the initialize method or how to call outside methods from within a method appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try what you describe? What about it doesn't work, or works differently than you expect? Do you get an error? Do you get different behavior than you expect, and if so how?

Comment: The rspec test was indicating that I was not calling the calculate_word_frequency method from within the Initialize method. The rspec test was likely reporting this due to me not dealing properly with local vs instance variables and so the rspec test wasn't seeing the output needed during it's testing of the code to confirm I was indeed calling the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right on calling the `calculate_word_frequency()` from the initialize method.

Where you're not getting the right output is that the instructions tell you:

```
#Implement the calculate_word_frequency() method to:
#* calculate the maximum number of times a single word appears within
#  provided content and store that in the highest_wf_count attribute.
#* identify the words that were used the maximum number of times and
#  store that in the highest_wf_words attribute.
#* identify the words that were used the maximum number of times and
# store that in the highest_wf_words attribute.
```

From your code

```
def calculate_word_frequency()
  words = content.split(" ")
  frequency = Hash.new
  highest_wf_count = Hash.new
  highest_wf_words = Hash.new
  words.each { |word| frequencies[word.downcase] += 1}
  frequencies = frequency.sort_by {|a, b| b }
  frequencies.reverse!
  highest_wf_count = frequencies.values[0].push
  highest_wf_words = frequencies.keys[0].push
end
```

You're simply storing the results in a local variable called `highest_wf_words` and `highest_wf_count`. I'm assuming when the tests call for `your_instance.highest_wf_words` it's attempting to read the instance variable value and returning `nil` since it hasn't been initialized.

The fix is simply to assign the value to the instance variable `@highest_wf_words` and `@highest_wf_count` instead of a local variable.

Comment: When I a change `highest_wf_words` and `highest_wf_count` to instance variables (`@highest_wf_words` and `@ highest_wf_count `) there is no change in rspec's test results for the initialize method. When I then add the `calculate_word_frequency()` line to the initialize method the rspec says everything fails except calling the calculate_word_frequency method. Do I need to at some point say `@highest_wf_words = highest_wf_words` and `@highest_wf_count = highest_wf_counts`?

Comment: In order to get a better context as to why your specs are failing it would be good to post the `spec` that is failing. The fix in my answer is still valid even if it doesn't fix your spec.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference in case someone else needs a little help here. 
I believe the order of the attributes should be accessors in the following order + calling calculate_word_frequency like this:

```
attr_accessor :content,
              :line_number,
              :highest_wf_count,
              :highest_wf_words

def initialize(content, line_number)
  @content = content
  @line_number = line_number
  @highest_wf_count = 0
  @highest_wf_words = 0
  calculate_word_frequency(content)
end
```